# Access visual components text, buttons in a Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame dialog

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi

I have a C++ app that makes use of a Webbrowser component. When a certain URL is open I get an standard Script Error dialog. I inspected the dialog and found out its type is *Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame*.

What I need to do is to close that dialog window. I already added a Window Hook and on the

WM_SHOWWINDOW I compare the title of the window and close it by sending a WM_CLOSE message.

The problem with that approach is that I cannot distinguish this window from other windows with the same title. So, What I'd need to do is to be able to access the text and the buttons in the 
***Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame*** dialog, in order to filter using its text and then click its *Yes* button.

I know how to get the child components from standard dialogs but I do not how to do it with this *Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame* dialog type. When I inspect it with WinSpy I can see that all the visual elements inside this dialog are encapsulated in *Internet Explorer_Server* element.

Does someone know how to access the visual components on the ***Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame*** dialog?

Thanks in advance for your help!